# ViewPager within AppBarLayout does not work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

With a ViewPager placed within the AppBayLayout, I get a cast exception between FrameLayout.LayoutParams and CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.  If I switch out ViewPager with an ImageView in the following xml, it works perfectly.  Any suggestions on what may work?  I'm looking to embed a slider of images that disappears when the webview is being scrolled up.  I've tried putting the ViewPager within other layouts, such as LinearLayout and FrameLayout, but same problem.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentListing2"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/lstWebviewDescription">
        </WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lstAppBarLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/lstImageAds"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
                <include
                android:id="@+id/lstToolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:foregroundGravity="top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the stack trace.  As you can see, the cause is deep within AppBarLayout and is somewhat misleading.  I first thought it was due to the NestedScrollView and kept working on that but after lots of experimentation, it turned out to be the ViewPager.  Also, please ignore the intellij part of the stack trace.  It's basically the same stack trace on the top when run on an android phone.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.updateOffset(AppBarLayout.java:1155)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onDependentViewChanged(AppBarLayout.java:1150)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.offsetChildToAnchor(CoordinatorLayout.java:1341)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.dispatchOnDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout.java:1109)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener.onPreDraw(CoordinatorLayout.java:1581)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.dispatchOnPreDraw(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:46)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:371)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:428)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the ClassCast exception is throwed?

Comment: Can you please post how you did this?

Comment: can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are putting your `ViewPager` inside the `AppBarLayout`. It should be outside the `AppBarLayout` but inside the `CoordinatorLayout`. Go through this project to know how: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Check out the layout there: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml

Comment: I wanted the collapsable image to be a set of sliding images so therefore the viewpager within AppBarLayout.  I have done material design with the viewpager outside as the primary viewer.  It works fine that way.